# OpenCV - using digital cameras.

Tags: python, opencv

The quality of video recording that is required for our project is not met by the webcams. Is it possible to use high megapixel digital cameras (Sony, Canon, Olympus) with OpenCV ?

How to talk to the digital cameras using OpenCV (and specifically using Python)

Comment: Could you clarify what type of camera you specifically mean?  OpenCV does support firewire (and I've specifically done OpenCV with a firewire stereocamera ... once I had the right adapter, OpenCV with python bindings worked essentially out of the box).  If you mean something like a higher version of the Canon Photoshot, I don't think you're going to be super thrilled about the quality if they do support streaming video; pretty sure USB 2.0 is the bottleneck and I don't know if any camera (designed for taking photos as opposed to something designed for taking video) has moved to USB 3.0

Comment: Note that you could do a basic sanity test by capturing the video on the camera and then sneaker-netting the test AVI over to your openCV system (it won't be live, but OpenCV can read AVI's as if they were camera devices)

Comment: *USB is the bottleneck*. Maybe that seals it, doesn't it? Even if I get a very high resolution camera, I won't be able to get the best it can do. Can you tell me if it is specifically possible to increase the FPS of a webcam ? That can maybe solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Install Drivers for required camera, connect it, and use `cv2.VideoCapture(int)`. Here, instead of 0, use a different integer according to the camera. By default, 0 is for the inbuilt webcam.

e.g.: `cv2.VideoCapture(1)`

Comment: That works only for USB powered WebCams. I was planning to use digital cameras that aren't as friendly.